# Start a login_activity if the user has not logged in

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I set a check method that opens login_activity if the user has not logged in - *isLogged*. App gets stuck on MessageRow activity even if user has not logged in.

```
//launcher activity


class MessageRow : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.message_row)
        supportActionBar?.title = "messages"
        supportActionBar?.setLogo(R.drawable.logo)

        isLogged()

    }

     private fun isLogged(){
     val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
     Log.e("tag","$uid") 
     if(uid == null){
         val intent = Intent(this,Login::class.java)
         intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
         startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat error

**E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!**

Comment: Could you edit the question with the exact error message?  Is this a compile time error or a runtime error?  Help us see what you see.

Comment: runtime error - getServiceInstance failed

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the entire relevant lines from logcat?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
```

into this:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser 
val uid  = user.uid
```